# Change a 2d array in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a initial state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = this.getInitialState();

    this.setSqValue = this.setSqValue.bind(this);
}

getInitialState() {
    return {
        allSq: new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill(null))
    };
}
```

Then in a method like `setSqValue` (called by clicking a button) when I assign a new value to a cell, strangely all other cells with any position in first dimensional and same position in second dimensional will take that value!

The second problem is that the state is changed while I didn't call any `setState`!

```
setSqValue(i, j) {
    console.log(i, j);

    let {allSq} = this.state;

    let value = 'foo';

    console.log('before', allSq);

    allSq[i][j] = value;

    console.log('after', allSq);

//    this.setState({allSq});
}
```

The output in the console is this :

[image: the output in the console]

You can see the before and after values are same (why?!).

The state in the React developer tool:

[image: the state in the react developer tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `Array`s are a special kind of `Object`, and if you pass an object to `fill()`, it uses the same object each time. You should use `map()` instead, which will create a copy of the array.

```
allSq: Array(3).fill().map(() => Array(3).fill(null))
```

To prevent the state from being changed you can use the `Object.freeze()` method:

```
allSq: Object.freeze(Array(3).fill().map(() => Object.freeze(Array(3).fill(null))))
```

With this, the line `allSq[i][j] = value;` will ether throw an error (in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)) or silently fail (outside of strict mode).

Comment: Thanks. But still the second problem is there. Assigning to allSq is changing the state without setState. I can see it in the react developer tool. However the app behavior is like there is nothing happening.

Comment: @AmirhosseinDZ See my edit. The app behaves as if nothing happened because React doesn't monitor the state object for changes; it only updates the components if state was changed by the `setState` method.

Answer (score 3):

In the chrome dev tools, objects aren't evaluated until you open them.  Hover on the little icon to the right and you will see `Object below was evaluated just now.` . Try putting a `debugger` in there and I have a feeling you will see that your `allSq` in the before doesn't have `foo` in there.  It seems as if everything is working correctly, you're just looking at the wrong things to see that.

Also, as another user said, `.fill` uses reference instead of value, so use `.map` instead.